# performSegueWithIdentifier causing Navigation to load incorrectly

Tags: ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have two Views part of a NavigationController hierarchy, one that displays a list of items and the second allows you to edit an item or add a new one.

On the parent view I have an add button on the right of the navigationbar once pressed performs a segue with identity "AddChild". Also, when the user taps on a table item, I perform another segue with identity "EditChild", all set up in storyboard.

In the case the user arrives at the parent view (with the list of items) but no items exist yet, I want to programatically perform the "AddChild" segue, so I added the following code in viewWillAppear: of the parent viewcontroller.

```
// if there are no children, send user to add screen
if (self.childListData.count == 0) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"AddChild" sender:self];
}
```

The child viewcontroller loads fine, but the navigation items are still of the previos view (a back button and an add button instead of a back button and a save button).

This is my prepareForSegue: method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    //  Get a reference to our detail view
    ChildDetailTableViewController *childDetail = (ChildDetailTableViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

    //  Pass the managed object context to the destination view controller
    childDetail.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;

    //  If we are editing a child we need to pass some stuff, so check the segue title first

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"EditChild"])
    {
        //  Get the row we selected to view
        NSInteger selectedIndex = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row];

        //  Pass the child object from the table that we want to view
        childDetail.currentChild = [childListData objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing so if anyone can help, I'd appreciate it.